# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\project\\genres\\blues\x08lues.00000.au'

Tags: python-3.x

When i write the following line of code

```
filename = 'E:\project\genres\blues\blues.00000.au'
```

I get the output as

```
'E:\\project\\genres\x08lues\x08lues.00000.au'
```

Why is 'b' from blues replaced by x08? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try adding two slashes like this : `filename = 'E:\\project\\genres\\blues\\blues.00000.au'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` is interpreted as backspace (much like `\n` is new line and `\t` is tab). See [list of ASCII control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII). `\x08` is the unicode representation of `\b`.

You need to either:

- Use double slashes

  ```
  filename = 'E:\\project\\genres\\blues\\blues.00000.au'
  ```
- Use forward slashes (Yes, these work on Windows)

  ```
  filename = 'E:/project/genres/blues/blues.00000.au'
  ```
- Use a raw-string literal

  ```
  filename = r'E:\project\genres\blues\blues.00000.au'
  ```

Comment: Kudos for the quick and rather complete answer; but really, please try to avoid answering questions which are obvious duplicates. We get this on a more or less daily basis.